# Apache mod_rewrite redirect if URL does not start with 'product'

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Went through different threads and documentation but I can´t figure out what´s wrong with my mod_rewrite rule:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/product$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.google.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

**Should redirect** user to google if he enters any **URL that does not start wir /product**.

But the following URI is also redirected to google for any reasons:
**https://example.com/product/some-product-name**

Has someone of you a hint for me?

Thanks a lot in advance & best!

Comment: You are demanding that the REQUEST_URI is not _exactly_ `/product`. You know what the `$` at the end means in regular expressions, right?

Comment: Damn... I´ve removed my (.*) for testing purposes... thanks :D

Comment: Well, RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/produkt gives the same result...

Comment: Make sure that’s not just your browser cache tricking you ... some browsers cache redirects really hard.